# Parse body.req inside a loop in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, post

How can i parse and save body of POST request with mongoose in Nodejs using a for loop, in order to avoid to save every property manually?

I would like to do something like

```
for(var param in body)
  Model.param=req.body.param;
```

instead of

```
Model.name=req.body.name;
Model.email=req.body.email;
Model.birth=req.body.birth;
...
```

considering also that some body parameters are **array**.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic not sure I see how destructuring would be any different than the solution the OP is looking to avoid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all

```
Object.assign(Model, req.body)
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer

Comment: Wow I didn't know this existed. Best answer.

Answer (score 5):

Code like this should work, even for the arrays.

```
for(var property in req.body) {
    Model[property] = req.body[property];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
for (let key of Object.keys(req.body)) {
  Model[key] = req.body[key]
}
```

`Object.keys()` is a safer way of getting all the keys instead of `in`. As **in** operator matches all object keys, including those in the object's prototype chain.

Comment: Identical answer to mine, but will require support of the `let` keyword.

Comment: let is supported by all the latest browsers and by node stable versions at this point

Comment: This is true, don't necessarily know all the background to their system though. Either syntax is valid